# Permission to run a script created by another user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a problem running a script that is set up by one person but I need to also be able to run and debug the script.

I am new to using Google Sheets scripting and do not understand the correct steps need to do to run a script setup by one person at a different location and I need to debug and run the same script on the same worksheet.

I have been given access to the worksheet and can edit the Google Sheet and edit the script but when I try to run the script using the interface run option or run the script on by using a button or the worksheet. It works fine in the original location, but does not work for me.

I am forced to give start to permission process but told that I need to contact the person that original created the worksheet it gives me his email address.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXel1.png]

Comment: Can you share an screenshot of the message you get?

Comment: I did as requested but did not get a answer back ?

Comment: This seems to have been a account permission, i had to register my email address with google under the subscription  to which the account is setup with !

Comment: Well I don't get a notification when you edit your question. The screenshot is the window to login and use the Script, this is expected. What happens after you login and accept the permissions?

Comment: I was just getting to figure out how this works, and it has to do with permission figured a workaround instead of increasing the active users to run the script.